# Contenido Wordpress personalizado

Tags: wordpress, plugin, cuenta-usuario

Buenas a todos mi pregunta es la siguiente, quiero hacer una página Wordpress en la cual los visitantes para acceder a cierto contenido se deban previamente registrar, y no solo eso, sino que dependiendo de con que perfil se hayan registrado `rensa, técnicos... vean en mi web un contenido u otro. Alguno sabe de alguna solucion, plugin a poder ser porque luego el ciente tendrá que mantenerla para hacer esto? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Eso lo proporciona el mismo WP, es una funcionalidad del mismo.

Suscriptor: Este usuario no puede crear contenidos, sólo verlos. Sus
capacidades son: ver el panel y editar su propio perfil. Es útil si
creamos una web privada en la que la web sólo la pueden ver los
usuarios registrados.

Colaborador: Puede crear borradores de contenido pero no publicarlos ya que el administrador debe aprobarlo primero.

Autor: Tiene los privilegios del Colaborador y además puede subir archivos y publicar entradas

Editor: Tiene todos los privilegios del Autor y además puede editar entradas y páginas, moderar comentarios y modificar categorías y enlaces.

Administrador: Todos los privilegios para administrar la web.

Fuente: http://sergiodelamo.es/wordpress-gestion-de-usuarios/